# [SOLVED]Deciding constant vector for angle calculation.

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

**EDIT - SOLUTION: the paper itself says which vector should be selected as reference vector, the one which gives the maximum positve distance**

**Due to my reputaion I can not attach all the necessary photo here so I just attached one single dropbox link**

I am trying to implement an algorithm below:

[image: THIS ONE.] I almost completed it only issue is that, the method described is working for single point correctly but when it comes to defining an error band for detection of object in noisy data we need to define a error band on the basis of neighbouring points and while I am doing that I am getting error because everytime the reference vector with which profile is calculated, is changing therefore the profile is always shifted.

I need a way to find a constant vector with which I can calculate the angle so that the profile shift is eliminated.

I am using dot product method to calculate angle between vectors.

[TO DROPBOX](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4hnbqfyq4qr5ynw/AAAytaXrO8n-wXpCX-45Yizla?dl=0)

Comment: The method says to "fit" a reference plane to the surface. A good "fitting" process would already use neighboring points and would account for the fact that the data are noisy. Why would you fit more than one reference plane or select more than one reference direction?

Comment: later in that paper we need to define tolarance band in which we need neighbouring points. Anyways I got the answer from the paper itself after reading it carefully it says we take the reference vector which gives the maximum positve distance. I did the same and got good results where I can deifne the tolarance band.